# Mysql query to find only exact value?

Tags: mysql

I have value in my db 
like
1,12,13,25,44,414,2114

I have to find exact 14 from the db.
but it also return the value 414 and 2114
but i want exact 14.
How can i achieve this through sql query Please help
i have tried this but didn't worked.

```
Select * from tb_name where columnNAme like '%value%'
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? It is not the question.

Comment: Provide your code, and make your question a bit more clear. Show us an example of what you are doing atm. Thanks!

Comment: Please, include your SQL statement to see where is the error.

Comment: i have tried this Select * from tb_name where columnNAme like '%value%'

Comment: @Akp include your code into your question, not into the comments.

Comment: Post the table structure, the query you have tried and what results you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want search exactly 14, then you need search `%,14,%`, but 14 may appears at start or at end of string, so you need add commas to column also.

Well, you can use:

```
select * from tb_name where concat(',',columnNAme ,',') like '%,14,%'
```

Side note, comma separated values in one column is bad database design

Comment: if i have value in db like 1,12,13,25,44,404,2113,14
then how to search

Comment: i mean to say that search value is at the end or can be in the beginng then how can i find that value

Comment: @OtoShavadze better solution for this bad database design was to use `FIND_IN_SET()` read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 2):

Select * from tb_name where columnNAme like 'value'
% - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters

Answer (score 0):

SELET * FROM database WHERE column LIKE 14 should work fine, just double checked it on my database.

If this doesn't work can you show your query please?

Above answer is correct, I didn't see your query before I posted this.

Comment: i have find value 14 but it also return that matches 14